# Get the log for last 10 minutes from nginx access log

Tags: shell-script, nginx

I want to filter the log written in the last 10 minutes in the access.log file of Nginx on Ubuntu 16.04. I tried using the below line but only the log for that minute is filtered.

```
awk -v d1="$(date --date="-10 min" "+%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M")" -v d2="$(date "+%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M")" '$0 > d1 && $0 < d2 || $0 ~ d2' /usr/local/nginx/logs/access.log
```

This is the date format for the logs that are written:
`12/Apr/2018:12:49:03`
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that nginx logs don't have the date at the beginning of the file:
thinking of this you get to this (mine was the 5th element on the line, notice the `$4` )

`sudo awk -v d1="$(date --date '-10 min' '+%d/%b/%Y:%T')" '$4 > d1' /var/log/nginx/access.log`

then again the issue is having the unrelated square bracket at the beginning:

So  removing the square bracket gives you something functioning:

`sudo awk -v d1="$(date --date '-10 min' '+%d/%b/%Y:%T')" '{gsub(/^[\[\t]+/, "", $4);}; $4 > d1' /var/log/nginx/access.log`

I have simplified the example a bit to demonstrate the issue but you can always  add back the upper boundaries checks if you wish to.

Comment: works perfectly! thank you for the answer.

Comment: This does not work on the 1st of each new month, when reading logs from the end of the previous month. It will simply list all the log entries.